# invalid predicate zcat

Tags: linux, bash, zcat

I'm trying to retrieve a file (.gz) and read it automatically after finding it, i want to include this in the [action] part of the 'find' command, unfortunately is for some reason not working.
What i'm doing is:

```
find . -name *20120805.gz -zcat
```

What i get is:
find: invalid predicate `-zcat'

Whats wrong with that action?
Any advice?

Comment: What do you think `-zcat` should do? Why?

Comment: I think you mean `find . -name *20120805.gz -exec zcat {} \;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is really invalid predicate. 
You must use `-exec` in this case:

```
$ find . -name *20120805.gz -exec zcat {} \;
```

For every file that was found, `find` runs `zcat` with the name of the file as an argument.